# Automorphism and center of a group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group.

Suppose $n$ is an integer such that the function $f(x)=x^n\;$is an automorphism of $G$.

The goal is to show that for all $x\in G$, we have $x^{n-1}\in Z(G)$ (the center of $G$).

I began with $x^{n-1}g$, for all $g\in G$, and I tried to use the automorphism, but I am not sure how to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a,b\in  G$.

We want to show $a^{n-1}b=ba^{n-1}$.

Since the map $x\mapsto x^n$ is an automorphism, we can write $b=c^n$, for some $c\in G$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&(ca)^n=c^na^n
&&\text{[since the map $x\mapsto x^n$ is a homomorphism]} \\[4pt]
\implies\;&c(ac)^{n-1}a=c^na^n\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(ac)^{n-1}=c^{n-1}a^{n-1}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(ac)^n=(ac)(c^{n-1}a^{n-1})\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a^nc^n=ac^na^{n-1}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a^{n-1}c^n=c^na^{n-1}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a^{n-1}b=ba^{n-1}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
as was to be shown.